# Скрыть букву в html документе

Tags: javascript

Каким образом скрыть букву **D** в html разметке при этом, чтобы сам блок не исчез.
То есть, буква D не должна показываться в html документе, а сам блок с цветом должен остаться.
Пробовал через **secondMenu.innerHTML = '';** но в этом случае блок с цветом иcчезает.

**Появилась идея придать opacity 0 букве D через JS, но как это сделать, я не могу понять.**

```js
let secondMenu = document.querySelector(".Menu_second_background");

secondMenu.textContent.style.opacity = '0'; // Не работает, я что-то упустил =(
```

```css
.Menu_second_background {
  background: gray;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
```

```html
<section class="Menu_second_background"> D </section>
<!-- Нужно скрыть эту букву при этом, 
                                                             чтобы блок с цветом остался ->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меняйте не прозрачность всего блока, а цвет и прозрачность только текста:

```js
let secondMenu = document.querySelector(".Menu_second_background");
secondMenu.style.color = '#0000';
```

```css
.Menu_second_background {
  background: gray;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
```

```html
<section class="Menu_second_background"> D </section>
```

Comment: Вот это чудеса, вы придали тексту черный цвет. Как текст исчез? Ведь тут нет прозрачности или что-то вроде этого.

Comment: @Домик: есть тут прозрачность - четвёртый ноль в значении цвета. Примерно то же, что и `rgba(0,0,0,0)`

Comment: #0000 это короткий вариант rgba(0,0,0,0)? Правильно?

Comment: @Домик: нет, это короткий вариант `#00000000`. `rgba(0,0,0,0)` - это немного другое, как и `hsla(0,0,0,0)`

Comment: А в моём случае что лучше rgba(0,0,0,0) или #0000? Какая разница между ними?

Comment: @Домик: в вашем случае, это не имеет значения. Различается только способом записи, и hex-нотация чуть короче. RGBA и HSLA лучше подходят, когда значения динамически формируются и изменяются. К тому же браузеры (Chrome, например) внутри всё равно приводят всё к RGB/RGBA.

Comment: Не знал этого, спасибо!

Comment: @Домик: в общем, раньше цвета не поддерживали альфа-канал, а в CSS3 добавили - это как раз четвёртое значение. Всё чаще встречается также такая [запись](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgb_%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82) `rgb(0 0 0 / 0)`.

Comment: И тут поставлю плюсики.

Comment: @Домик: ну, спасибо. Столько палок, хоть дом строй )))

Comment: Что за палки???